# Fragments with different depth are blended

Tags: opengl

I am wondering about the rendering behavior. I am rendering text mesh "orange" and rectangle mesh "blue". I am using opengl pipeline for rendering.
The depth function is set to `GL_LESS` and both meshes are such, that all fragments of Rectangle has slightly larger values then text fragments (due to resolution and tolerance errors).

I assumed that all text fragments should be discarded (rectangle depth values), but final image contains a blend of rectangle and text (blending is also disabled):
[image: Original text color]
[image: Text with rectangle overlay]

B.t.w. renderdoc in Texture view shows a rectangle without text overlay as expected, but in preview, text is seen. This is also something I would like to understand. Do I miss some pipeline postprocessing stages that are in action?
[image: renderdoc tracing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) may not work as you expect when the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is enabled. The depth test discards the fragments before they can be blended. If depth test and blending are enabled, a fragment that is not discarded during the depth test will be blended. So it depends on the order in which the objects are drawn.
To achieve correct blending of objects with different depths, draw all objects in order from back to front (depth sorting). Since the objects are drawn from back to front, the depth test is not needed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, as i can see alpha values for all fragments are set to 1. factors are set to GL_SRC_ALPHA and  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA for source and destination fragments respectively. Thus I expected that the color of the fragment that is nearer to the camera is drawn without blending with whatever is on the screen.

Thus I thought this 2 variants text is further from camera and plane is nearer to the camera:

1. Plane is drawn first, text is afterwards. In this case text fragments are discarded during late depth test.

Comment: @IvanFolbort No. If there was drawn a transparent fragment (alpha 0) before, which is closer to the camera, the new fragment is discarded by the depth test.

Comment: 2. variant: the text is drawn first then plane. In this case fragments of the plane are blended with fragments of text, but taking into account defined blend functions text fragments should be blended out. As a result I expected that plane overrides text. But in reality, I get text fragments blended with planes, which I cannot explain by blending configurations..

Comment: @IvanFolbort No idea what you're talking about. That is not complicated at all. If it doesn't t work for you, the you have to find the bug in your code.

Comment: I agree:)

B.t.w. Just for reference, If I disable blending all fragments are still blended at the end the same way as in the description.

Comment: Ok, it feels to me that as you explained, ~50% of text fragments are uniformly discarded during the depth test, thus final image looks blended.